# Ubuntu live stick

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, bootable-media, liveusb

I downloaded a Ubuntu image from the official website and tried to burn it to my 8gb usb drive. I did that with "ISO to USB" on my Windows computer. This procedure worked perfectly fine for everything else till now. So I made a Bootable usb stick with this. When I plug it into my other computer and put the usb device at the first place in bios boot order, it says "Remove Drive. Press any key to reboot." When I press something, it only gets to my grub bootloader on my ssd.

What else can I to do make this stick Bootable, cause apparently it is not...

Thanks. Jukisu.

Answer (score 0):

I had this once. [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie) worked well for me in my situation. Other software I tried didn't set the boot flag on the USB, so the ISO got transferred to the USB drive but was never made boot able. Might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

ImageWriter (Win32DiskImager) solved it for me.
I don't know why ISO to USB didn't work, cause I always used this, but in this case, everything worked by using ImageWriter.